Reverse distribution in DDPMs
In Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models, we want to reverse a forward process where we blend gaussian noise into a data point $\mathbf{x}_0$ over $T$ steps. The result of each forward step applied to an input $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$ is distributed according to $q(\mathbf{x}_t | \mathbf{x}_{t-1})$, and the reverse is distributed according to $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t)$. Each step blends in Gaussian noise according to a step size $\beta_t$, so that:
$q(\mathbf{x}_t | \mathbf{x}_{t-1}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_T; \sqrt{1 - \beta_t}\mathbf{x}_{t-1}; \beta_T\mathbf{I})$

In both the Dickstein and Ho papers and a few other treatments online, the reverse process is modeled as a Gaussian because (from Dickstein, which references a very old result from Feller 1949):

Since $q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t−1})$ is a Gaussian (binomial) distribution, and if $\beta_t$ is small, then $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}|\mathbf{x}_{t})$ will also be a Gaussian (binomial) distribution.

However, the conditional probability $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$ which is used for the variational lower bound proof can be shown to be gaussian by applying Bayes' rule to the forward process distributions, without making assumptions on the step size $\beta_t$ (see equation 53 in this blog post). By total probability, we can compute $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t)$ as a sum of this over all samples $\mathbf{x}_0$ in our dataset, and sums of independent gaussians are gaussian.
So when we assert that the reverse step is gaussian, do we actually need to reference the step size?

I made a dumb mistake in my reasoning: total probability is about the sum of the PDFs. Multiple gaussians summing to another gaussian is a property of random variables, not PDFs.
So it's not true that the posterior $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t)$ is gaussian even though $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_{t}, \mathbf{x}_0)$ is. It's interesting that there is a gaussian mixture model formula for the reverse distribution though (if I understand the model correctly).
